# How to make parameterized Express route work with or without trailing backslash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I have a very simple app that always will be accessed using the following URL structure: `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890/`

Where the 1234567890 is a user's account number which can be different per user.  Currently the app cannot be accessed if the final trailing backslash is left off as so: `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890`

In fact, the URL changes if the app is accessed this way to: `www.myapplication.com/1234567890`

Given the following in my app.js:

```
app.use('/', api);
app.use('/:user', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

Where api is a simple express router itself which my React app calls using jQuery that uses the user number from the req.params, how can I make the application accessible using either the trailing backslash or not?

I've tried various methods such as:

```
app.use('/:user/?', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

or

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

The later prevents the url being truncated, but only works without the user's account number, which is obviously necessary: `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/`

If I go to `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890` or `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890/`

the url is not truncated, but I get `Cannot GET /1234567890` or `Cannot GET /1234567890/`.

I've also tried shuffling the positions to no avail:

```
app.use('/:user', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/', api);
```

Comment: have you tried with app.use('/:user*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); ?

Comment: Just tried that and it truncates the url when I leave off the trailing backslash.  When I access the route with the trailing backslash it gets the static files but shows a 303 (See Other) and then tries to go to the truncated url and get them at: www.myapplication.com/1234567890/main.js/, etc.

Comment: /some/deep/nested/route is static, or dynamic? you could try with app.use('/some/deep/nested/route*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); if it's a static path

Comment: No, that just requires me to go to www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/some/deep/nested/01234567890/

The base of the app.use('/', api); is /some/deep/nested/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a hacky, work-around way to do this that is pretty specific to my situation and wouldn't work in most cases.  I'll post it here so others can improve on the answer.  I added the following middleware:

```
app.use('/', api);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.url.substr(-1) !== '/' && req.url.length > 1 && req.url.substr(-3) !== 'css' && req.url.substr(-2) !== 'js'){
    res.redirect(301, '/some/deep/nested' + req.url + '/');
  }else{
    next();
  }
});
app.use('/:user', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

The if statement checks for css and js files and prevents the backslash from being added to them (a problem I was seeing before adding those checks).

Again, this works for the specific situation I'm facing, but I'm hoping that there is some better answer lurking out there.

Answer (score 0):

I use [express-slash](https://github.com/ericf/express-slash) for this. It's a simple middleware that appends a trailing slash when it's not present. Then you only need to handle the route that includes the trailing slash. This is arguably preferable, as `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890` and `www.myapplication.com/some/deep/nested/1234567890/` are different paths, and rendering the same response for both is not ideal (in terms of SEO, most pertinently).

Comment: Thanks for the response, while express-slash does add the backslash to the request, the app is still truncating the url before that trailing backslash is added.  This results in `www.myapplication.com/1234567890/ when the request goes through which does not work.  I guess the root of the problem is why is Express (or Node.js) truncating the url when the trailing backslash is missing.